# Selenium Webdriver tests not running on Chrome headless due to "unable to connect to renderer" error

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

Chrome version running: 67.0.3396.79

Chromedriver version: 2.40.0 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/chromedriver)

When running the selenium webdriver tests in Chrome headless mode, getting error:

```
SessionNotCreatedError: session not created exception
     from disconnected: unable to connect to renderer
       (Session info: headless chrome=67.0.3396.79)
       (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7),platform=Linux 3.13.0-74-generic x86_64)
         at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/jenkins/workspace/1-sunrise-e2e-tests-dev/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
```

Comment: Those are old versions of chrome and chromedriver.  Is there a reason that you're not running latest?

Comment: I tried the latest versions but still get the same error. Chrome version: 74.0.3729.131 and Chromedriver: 74.0.3729.6

Answer (score 0):

Goodness me! Looks like the issue was with '--remote-debugging-port=9222', which I added to the headless Chrome options, removing that, fixed it.